# Timing of static variable declaration

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

In C# 4.0 and later, is it (strictly) defined (in any possible compiler?) when static variables of a class are created, namely their memory allocated? Can I be sure that before entering the constructor of any created instance, a static variable of that class has already been allocated?

Please see the following example:

```
class X
{
static Vector2 v = new Vector2();

public X()
  {
  v.Set(1,1); // Can I be sure that memory for v is allocated here ? Always ??
  }
}
```

Is this considered good programming practice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can be sure about that. You can refer to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) link. I don't see the purpose of setting that vector that way, though. Maybe you'd prefer a static constructor, such as:

```
static X()
{
   v.Set(1, 1);
}
```

Comment: @spender Thank you for editing my post with the updated version of the documentation, I should've checked.

Comment: +1 especially for noting that setting a static field in an instance constructor is most likely asking for trouble.  I would also note that the `Set` method implies a mutable struct, which is also asking for trouble.